# Position one div next to another div which is positioned in center

Tags: html

I want to position a `div` to the right of another `div` which is positioned in the center of the screen with a `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`.

I tried to wrap the two divs into one doesn't seem to work because it center the wrapper rather than the first div.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

My css code so far:

```
#text {
width: 500px;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 150px;
}

#image {
overflow: hidden;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code and show what you've already tried.

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DEXNr/ (note: on a small screen such as an iphone, the sidebar will be hidden)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the `css`; do you have your `html` as well?

Try pulling the `div` outside of the wrapper; your positioning should work.  If it continues to give you problems, try

```
{position: absolute;}
```

Comment: yeah, I was thinking I might have to do something with absolute and relative positions, but am not very much acquainted with those tags.

Comment: my HTML for the moment is really straightforward, just the two divs below each other.

Comment: You've got it.  As long as your div is not inside of the wrapper div, the positioning will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but this seems to work well (at least in Chrome).

```
<div style="position:relative; width:50%; border:1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    centered text
    <div style="position:absolute; left:100%; top:-1px; width:50px; border:1px solid red">
        right text
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The `position: relative;` attribute on the outer `div` make the absolute positioning of the inner div "relative" to the outer div. Just using `position: relative;` on the inner `div` yields different results (though you might get it to work with some effort).

Positioning the inner `div` to `left:100%;` brings the left border of the inner `div` to the right border of the outer `div`. The `top:-1px;` is being used to compensate for the border on the outer `div`. If you don't have a border, `top:0px;` should suffice. The `width` on the inner `div` could be set to a percentage of the outer `div`'s width.

I'd recommend dropping this into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and play around with the attributes until you get it just right. You'll also want to test in your target browsers of choice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I would imagine to do it is by using a margin on your left div to make it position in the centre then float your second div left to butt up to it so it would be

```
<div style="position:relative;float:left;width:800px;margin:0 auto">
 <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:500px;margin:0 0 0 150px">
  This should go to the centre of the centred 800px div
 </div>
 <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:150px">
  This will be pushed up to the left of the centred 500px div
 </div>
</div>
```

I think this is less 'hacky'...